# DialogFlow - Routing user questions to Knowledge Bases

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am trying to achieve a specific use case with DialogFlow.

I have a list of countries and a knowledge base Q&A ser for each country. The questions for each country is similar, only the answers differ.

So I have to detect the country as an entity and route the question to the specific KB for that country.
[Link to design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6aSA.png)

This is easily possible with Luis and QnAMaker, but struggling with DialogFlow.

Please suggest if there is a way to achieve this.

Comment: I'm looking for the same solution. Did you ever figure out what to do here? By writing javascript code I can intercept the response, but here (as you know) we need to intercept the request.

Answer (score 1):

Dialogflow provides the [@sys.geo-country](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/system-entities) System Entity which can be used to detect countries in conversation using entities.
You can follow [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/#4) to setup your entity.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Creating the entity is not a problem. But routing to different knowledge bases based on the entity value is something I couldn't find.